# In Python v3.7.x, How Can a Called Function Obtain the Name of the Calling Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pythonistas,

In Python v3.7.x, or later, how can a called function obtain the name of the calling function...WITHOUT programming the calling function's name as an argument?

In the code example below, how can **NAME_OF_CALLING_FUNCTION** be populated with...well...the name of the calling function? (Say...something to do with the Standard Library? Dunders/Magic Names?)

- To be clear: This request for assistance is **not** about using
  Python's logging module (used here only as an example); it is
  about a called function being able to auto-magically obtain the name
  of the calling function.

Example code:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log_file.log',
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = A_VALID_FORMAT_STRING)

def logging_function(log_message):
    #Simplified for StackOverflow
    msg = str(NAME_OF_CALLING_FUNCTION) + ' DEBUG: Something...'
    logging.debug(msg)

def caller_one():
    #Simplified for StackOverflow
    logging_function(DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE_ONE)
    return(0)

def caller_two():
    #Simplified for StackOverflow
    logging_function(DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE_TWO)
    return(0)

def main():
    #Simplified for StackOverflow
    caller_one()
    caller_two()
```

Ideally, when `caller_one()` and `caller_two()` execute, `my_log_file.log` will contain something like this:

```
DATE/TIME Calling function: caller_one DEBUG: Something...
DATE/TIME Calling function: caller_two DEBUG: Something...
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

With gratitude,
*Plane Wryter*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `inspect` module. From [this source](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python_inspect/):

```
import inspect
# functions
def whoami():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]
def whosdaddy():
    return inspect.stack()[2][3]
def foo():
    print "hello, I'm %s, daddy is %s" % (whoami(), whosdaddy())
    bar()
def bar():
    print "hello, I'm %s, daddy is %s" % (whoami(), whosdaddy())
johny = bar
# call them!
foo()
bar()
johny()
```

```
hello, I'm foo, daddy is ?
hello, I'm bar, daddy is foo
hello, I'm bar, daddy is ?
hello, I'm bar, daddy is ?
```

**in your case:**

```
msg = str(inspect.stack()[1].function) + ' DEBUG: Something...'
```

Example:

```
import inspect

def logging_function(log_message):
    #Simplified for StackOverflow
    msg = str(inspect.stack()[1].function) + ' DEBUG: Something...'
    print(msg)

def f1():
    logging_function("")

def f2():
    logging_function("")

f1()
f2()
```

```
f1 DEBUG: Something...
f2 DEBUG: Something...
```

Comment: Many, many thanks! Beautiful solution...clearly expressed. With appreciation...Plane Wryter